# How to call jquery function after calling wicket ajax submit button

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, wicket

I have a form with a submit button but this is implemented by Wicket's AjaxButton class. When the HTML page renders Wicket keeps a javascript onClick method dynamically for that submit button.

I want to do some operations using JQuery after Wicket's onClick method completes. How do I do this?

Answer (score 11):

Using JQuery or any other JavaScript library works like a charm in wicket if you do it right.

First of all you need to make sure the library is present. You usually do that using a [JavascriptPackageResource](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/JavascriptPackageResource.html).

```
add(JavascriptPackageResource.getHeaderContribution("/path/to/jquery.js"));
```

(Put this in a constructor or dynamic initializer or in [onBeforeRender()](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#onBeforeRender%28%29))

Then, you need to make sure that

1. your component has an id (use [`Component.setOutputMarkupId(true)`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#setOutputMarkupId%28boolean%29)) and
2. you are using the correct id in the
   JQuery function (always retrieve the id via [`Component.getMarkupId()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#getMarkupId%28%29))

Here's an example with a button that turns blue when clicked:

```
add(new AjaxButton("id"){

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form){
        target.appendJavascript(
            "$('#" +getMarkupId() +"').css({'background':'blue'})");
    }
}.setOutputMarkupId(true));
```

Answer (score 8):

```
protected void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target){
   target.appendJavascript("alert('hello');");
)
```

Comment: In appendJavascript if you pass any JQuery function name, it is not working. For simple javascripts like alert is OK.

Comment: if it doesn't work, you are probably doing something wrong. It *should* work that way. (+1)